# ValidatedField in jhipster, that uses react-hook-form - how to use this as a field within a component ie. not direct descendant of ValidatedForm?

Tags: reactjs, jhipster, react-hook-form

I have

```
 <ValidatedForm onSubmit={saveEntity}>
                {step1Questions && step1Questions.map((question, index) => <FormQuestion question={question} key={index} />)}
```

and then in FormQuestion

```
const FormQuestion = ({ question }: FormQuestionProps) => {
  const { register } = useForm();
  switch (question.questionType) {
    case 'text':
      return (
        <ValidatedField
          label={question.questionText}
          id="questionnaire-'${question.questionName}'"
          name={question.questionName}
          data-cy={question.questionName}
          type="text"
        />
      );
    case 'radio':
```

But validation doesn't work -  in the docs in the code it says -
" * For complex use cases or for nested children, use Reactstrap form elements or ValidatedField or ValidatedInput and pass methods and values from react-hook-form's `useForm` hook"

But it doesn't really say which methods and values. If I wanted to add validation to the above, how would i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with something similar. You might want to see if you have access to the `validated-form.tsx` file because this is were you'll find the code for `ValidatedForm` and `ValidatedField`. Taking a look at these helped me to use the `useForm` hook.

Posted Here for Reference

```
    export function ValidatedForm({ defaultValues, children, onSubmit, mode, ...rest }: ValidatedFormProps): JSX.Element {
      const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        reset,
        setValue,
        formState: { errors, touchedFields, dirtyFields },
      } = useForm({ mode: mode || 'onTouched', defaultValues });

      useEffect(() => {
        reset(defaultValues);
      }, [reset, defaultValues]);

      return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} {...rest}>
          {React.Children.map(children, (child: ReactElement) => {
            const type = child?.type as any;
            const isValidated =
              type && child?.props?.name && ['ValidatedField', 'ValidatedInput', 'ValidatedBlobField'].includes(type.displayName);

            if (isValidated) {
              const childName = child.props.name;
              const elem = {
                ...child.props,
                register: child.props.register || register,
                error: child.props.error || errors[childName],
                isTouched: typeof child.props.isTouched === 'undefined' ? touchedFields[childName] : child.props.isTouched,
                isDirty: typeof child.props.isDirty === 'undefined' ? dirtyFields[childName] : child.props.isDirty,
                key: childName,
              };
              if (type.displayName === 'ValidatedBlobField') {
                const defaultValue = defaultValues[childName];
                const defaultContentType = defaultValues[`${childName}ContentType`];
                elem.setValue = typeof child.props.setValue === 'undefined' ? setValue : child.props.setValue;
                elem.defaultValue = typeof child.props.defaultValue === 'undefined' ? defaultValue : child.props.defaultValue;
                elem.defaultContentType =
                  typeof child.props.defaultContentType === 'undefined' ? defaultContentType : child.props.defaultContentType;
              }
              return React.createElement(type, { ...elem });
            }
            return child;
          })}
        </Form>
      );
    }
```

## Answer

So `ValidatedForm` looks at it's children and checks to see if it's a `ValidatedField` or `ValidatedInput` etc. If it's not then it doesn't do the `useForm` hook stuff. In your code, `FormQuestion` is the immediate child and so it doesn't do the `useForm` stuff.

Instead, you'll have to do it manually. First, get rid of the `ValidatedForm` and replace it with `Form` like you see in the code snippet. Then, copy the `useForm` code and place it into your code, you'll probably have to make small adjustments. Most importantly, you'll want to add `register: register` inside you're `ValidatedField` tag

So in the end, it should look something like

```
const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        reset,
        setValue,
        formState: { errors, touchedFields, dirtyFields },
      } = useForm({ mode: 'onTouched', defaultValues });

<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveEntity)}>
                {step1Questions && step1Questions.map((question, index) => <FormQuestion question={question} key={index} />)}

const FormQuestion = ({ question }: FormQuestionProps) => {
  switch (question.questionType) {
    case 'text':
      return (
        <ValidatedField
          register: register
          label={question.questionText}
          id="questionnaire-'${question.questionName}'"
          name={question.questionName}
          data-cy={question.questionName}
          type="text"
        />
      );
    case 'radio':
```